# routing not working properly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying out routing in AngularJS.When i click on 'li' 2,i want to display contents of secondScreen.html.Following is my code.I dont know what is going wrong in it.Can anyone tell me what i am missing?

AngularJS file : app.js

```
var sampleApp = angular.module("sampleApp",['ngRoute','ngResource']);

sampleApp.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl : '/templates/firstScreen.html', 
        controller : 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/secondScreen',{         
        templateUrl : '/templates/secondScreen.html', 
        controller : 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/thirdScreen',{          
        templateUrl : '/templates/thirdScreen.html', 
        controller : 'mainController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
});

sampleApp.controller("mainController",["$scope","$log","$resource","$location",function($scope,$log,$resource,$location){

$scope.tabValue = 1;    
$scope.statesAndCapitals = [{state:'Maharashtra',capital:'Mumbai'},{state:'Goa',capital:'Panji'}]

$scope.contacts = [{name:"Steve Jose",mobile : "9872314642",address : "Nasik"}];

$scope.submit = function(tab){
    $scope.tabValue = tab;
    if(tab==1){
        $location.path = '/';
        $log.log("changed path to 1");
    }
    else if(tab==2){
        $location.path = '#/secondScreen';
        $log.log("changed path to 2");
    }
    else if(tab==3){
        $location.path = '#/thirdScreen';
        $log.log("changed path to 3");
    }
}   

$scope.saveContact = function(){

};

}]);
```

HTML contents :

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="submit(1)" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary' : tabValue==1,'btn btn-default' : tabValue!=1}">Find Capitals</li>
            <li ng-click="submit(2)" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary' : tabValue==2,'btn btn-default' : tabValue!=2}">Add Contact</li>
            <li ng-click="submit(3)" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary' : tabValue==3,'btn btn-default' : tabValue!=3}">Show Contacts</li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

I am getting the logs after changing $location.path.But its not getting displayed.

This is my secondScreen.html :

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
<form ng-submit="saveContact()">
    Name : <input type="text"><br/><br/>
    Age : <input type="number" min=1 max=150><br/><br/>
    Gender : 
    <input type="radio" ng-model="gender" ng-value="Male">Male<br/>

    <input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="Female">Female<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: use anchor tag in li and set the path on href

Comment: you dont need to use click function to change the path 

            <li  ng-class="{'btn btn-primary' : tabValue==2,'btn btn-default' : tabValue!=2}"><a href="#/second" > Add Contact </a></li>
like this

Comment: When using location service, i don't think you need to prefix `#`. Set the path without hash and see.

Comment: @Chandermani I tried out without # as well but it didnt work

Comment: @Ahmer but $location.path should also work,right?

Comment: if you dont need to functions route use html trick because functions make slow your executions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$location.path('/');`

instead of

`$location.path="/"`

see [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)